# In Eclipse how to show retrived information from url

Tags: android

So I am very new to programming and have been trying to figure out how to send login information to the web url and have it log the user in and come back displaying the page. Again I am very new but this is the code I have

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setting default screen to login.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonclk);

     Button bhome1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        bhome1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new      
Intent("beats.us.with.Loginretrieve"));
                mpButtonClick.start();
            }
        } ) ;   



}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);


    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Followed by Loginretrive

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
```

public class Loginretrieve extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = "http://beatswith.us";


} 



}
```

Again im very new so any help would be kewl 
telling me to go to the android developer page and read is like telling me what i already know thats why im on here trusting in ppls knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to add the internet permission to your manifest.xml which is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.
then inside your Loginretrieve activity you'll need to create your request (post/get request) as follows:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {

        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        responseString = getResponseString(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the `getResponseString` method is:

```
public static String getResponseString(HttpResponse response)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

    String responseString = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        responseString = sb.toString();

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

that's it.... you've made the request and retrieved the response.. Hope this helps.